# iOS: Text being cut-off when using italics and opacity together

Tags: ios, css

In iOS (only tested iPad so far)...

Italicized text is being cut-off as soon as I change its opacity to anything less than 1. Turning off either opacity or italics solves the issue. If both properties exists, then it seems the text gets cut-off.

Codepen:
    https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJbQym

Attached image showing the issue:

[image]

The word is "jello?" and you see the start of 'j' and end of '?' are cut-off.

Tested on iPad in all the latest browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Edge) and using Safari remote debugger on Macos to investigate.

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#wrapper {
      font-size: 2em;     
      display: grid;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="title">jello?</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```